# Set AttributeConsumingService index?

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, service-provider, sustainsys-saml2

I'am doing an connection to IDP with sustainsys SAML2 with the Saml2AuthenticationModule and Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule

Since I want metadata returned I need to set
AttributeConsumingService index from 0(default) to 1.
Tried to find ways to change it without success. Anyone knows how?

```
    <AttributeConsumingService index="0" isDefault="true">
            <ServiceName xml:lang="en">SP</ServiceName>
            <RequestedAttribute isRequired="true" Name=...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the value in Startup.cs

```
.AddSaml2("IDP", "IDP", opt =>
{
    opt.SPOptions = new Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SPOptions
    {
        EntityId = new EntityId(ipdUrl),
        ReturnUrl = new Uri(webSiteUrl),
        ModulePath = string.Format("/saml2/{0}", "idp"), 
        AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = SigningBehavior.Always,
        MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
    };

    RequestedAttribute requestedAttributeEmail = new RequestedAttribute("email");
    requestedAttributeEmail.FriendlyName = "Email";
    requestedAttributeEmail.NameFormat = RequestedAttribute.AttributeNameFormatBasic;
    requestedAttributeEmail.IsRequired = false;

    AttributeConsumingService attributeConsumingService = new AttributeConsumingService();

    attributeConsumingService.RequestedAttributes.Add(requestedAttributeEmail);

    attributeConsumingService.ServiceNames.Add(new LocalizedName("Required attributes", "en"));
    attributeConsumingService.IsRequired = true;
    attributeConsumingService.Index = 1;
    attributeConsumingService.IsDefault = true;

    opt.SPOptions.AttributeConsumingServices.Add(attributeConsumingService);    
});
```

Comment: This is sadly not possible with the httpmodule and web.config

Comment: I'd need a lot more context to your situation to provide any further advice.  It appears you are not using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: asp.net 4.8.. I solved it by downloading the sourcecode from git and added the possiblites to setting the attributeConsumingService.Index